# How to open/edit a file in Python for Windows without locking it?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, pywin32

I've installed pypiwin32 already, so I can use the win32file command, but I don't have much experience with Python.

How would I change my code below that opens a couple of files (I'm not worried about locking the first one), reads a line then replaces/writes a part of a line in the second file? I don't want the second file to get locked while it's open/writing, hence utilizing Win32 API.

```py
with open("C:\\Temp\\Fileorg.txt", "rt") as fin:
 with open("C:\\Temp\\File2.txt", "wt") as fout:
  for line in fin:
   fout.write(line.replace('part/list.txt', 'part/list.txt?id='+text))
```

Comment: @ser If that were correct (like, any of it), how would you explain that there's a [LockFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-lockfile) API? As always, if you do not understand an API, feel free to not comment on it.

Comment: @IInspectable: LockFile is intented to synchronize collaborating processes that share a inherited handle. AFAIK it is not required to prevent  *independant* process to access a file.

Comment: @ser That's missing the point. I was commenting on the statement *"Opening a file under Windows OS locks it. Full point."* which is provably wrong. Requesting to open a file and locking regions of its backing store are orthogonal operations. So... opening a file on Windows does not lock it. Someone that doesn't understand the difference between sharing modes and file locking should maybe not comment on a question about sharing modes and file locking.

Comment: @IInspectable; I agree with this part. And I know the difference between *locking* and *sharing*. But as English is not my first language, I often re-use OP's words. As nothing in OP's code was related to true *locking* I (I admit incorrectly) re-used *locks* for *prevents another process to access the file*. My only goal was to warn OP that simultaneously opening a file in independant processes on Windows OS is far from straightforward.

Comment: To me it seems while using my code above, Windows is unable to read the file while Python is still writing to it, so I was reading the post below where he has code that is allowing Python to open/write to the file and it is not locked by Windows as you can actually delete the file while it is still being used by Python/Windows but I have no idea how to implement it into my process - http://thepythoncorner.com/dev/how-to-open-file-without-locking-it/

Comment: @SergeBallesta I think you mean the file is locked with it's opened for writing.

Comment: If you are adding text to end of file then just wait for it to finish. If you are adding text in the middle of the file, then you have rewrite the whole file. Windows API won't be much help in that case.

Comment: I was initially wrong. If you manage to open the file using `CreateFile` and specify a share mode of FILE_SHARE_READ, subsequent opens in read more will succeed. In my tests I succeeded with `CreateFileA(file, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);` but from a C program, because I am too lazy to install pypiwin32 or any other library giving direct access to the Win32 API, hence posting a comment and not an answer. But if you combine my `CreateFile` and the above link, it should work. Do not forget to post an answer when done.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I'm not really adding text to the end but replacing apart of the text string at the end of a line.

Answer (score 0):

New line symbol is just the character `'\n'`. If the file is `"line1\nline2"` and it is changed to `"line1X\nline2"` then everything after `'\n'` has to be re-written. Output file has to be locked.

In this scenario, it is possible to use file sharing to read characters before `X`. But it is a big challenge to read characters in the right sequence, on and after `X`.

- The best option is to use a database
- A second option is to write to a temporary file `"temp.tmp"`. Once the operation is
  finished, copy the whole file from `"temp.tmp"` to `"File2.txt"`. Copying files is fast. The reader can check if the file is available, if it is not, it should wait 1 second for `CopyFile` to finish, and try again, up to 5 times (I made up the numbers 1 and 5)
- A third option is to use formatted text. For example, the output file is

  ```
    0line1####
    0line2####
    0line3####
  ```

You can modify this data only by changing the `#` characters. The `0` at the start of each line indicates that line is not busy. If the writer is updating the line, it changes `0` to `1`, and back.

This way the file size doesn't change when data is changed, you can use file sharing and find data in the right place. You can add data but deleting data would be harder. This would be a big project.

Comment: Okay, I can try the Second option, how would I implement that into my code above? Thank you